# how can I block internet access for non-domain computer windows server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, dhcp, windows

Is there any GPOs that allow me to block an non-domain computers ? 
I tried to use IPAM for blocking an ip address but it does not work! What should i use ?

Comment: What does this actually mean??  FFS, come on.  [Read this and learn how to ask a useful question that has a chance of getting a useful answer](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/3608/118258) instead of wasting everyone's time.  Then come back and fix your question or try again.

Comment: Use google. Find someone to hire that knows how to administrate your network, or at least how to ask a meaningful question. THen have him solve the problem. Please. It is totally unclear what you try to do. And why you think IPAM may help you.

Comment: I don't need someone to hire how to administrate my network. i resolved my problem without your help!

Answer (score 1):

There is no such Thing using Group Policy. Group Policy implies that you are in the Domain (to configure it centrally)

What you can Research is using a Proxy which does some Kind of authentication